# javac e java command-line

Tags: java, javac

Assuming I have the following folder structure:

- myProject

  - source

    - com

      - wickedlysmart

        - MyClass.java
  - classes

    - com

      - wickedlysmart

        - MyClass.class

Which command 'java.exe' I would use to run the class MyClass.class, admitting that I was in folder 'source'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever command you are using for running MyClass.class in its folder plus navigation to the Myclass.class.

Let's say you are using

```
java MyClass
```

to run it from it's directory. Now you have to use

```
java -cp ../../myproject/classes com.wickedlysmart.MyClass
```

to run from some other directory

Comment: I think you should assume the class is in package `com.wickedlysmart`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Why? It's not under `com` in either sources or classes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Even then he should assume it is in package `wickedlysmart`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That, I agree with.

Comment: I am wondering why my answer got negative points? Would you please let me know if you are the one giving it a negative point?

Comment: Technically you can remove `../myproject/` from the classpath

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the classpath for the classes folder, so you need to do:

```
java -cp ../classes com.wickedlysmart.MyClass
```

Or

```
java -cp <full-path-to>/classes com.wickedlysmart.MyClass
```

Note: This is assuming that you made an error in your post with the hierarchy with having `com` and `wickedlysmart` on the same level. If they should be on the same level, remove the `com.` from above examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
java -cp myProject/classes com.wickedlysmart.MyClass
```